# Does a Fujifilm FinePix have a long exposure feature?

Tags: long-exposure, fujifilm

I own a Fujifilm Finepix s2980 and I can't find the long exposure. 
I would like to know if I have this feature or not in my camera.

Comment: What does the *User Manual* say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to these [specifications published by Fuji](http://www.fujifilm.eu/uk/products/digital-cameras/super-zoom-bridge/model/finepix-s2980/specifications/), the longest shutter speed possible in *Auto Mode* is 1/4 second. In all other modes the longest possible shutter speed setting is 8 seconds.

The instructions for manually selecting the shutter speed using *Shutter Priority Mode* can be found on page 27 of the *[S2900 Series Owner's Manual](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/manuals/pdf/index/s/finepix_s2900_manual_en.pdf)*. Instructions for controlling both shutter speed and aperture in *Manual Mode* are found on page 29.

Many similar cameras limit exposure times due to the smaller sensor size. The longer the exposure, the warmer the sensor heats up. This causes increase *noise* in the image. All other things being equal smaller sensors are inherently noisier than larger ones because they collect less light than the larger sensors can. Since *image noise* is a result of a low *signal-to-noise ratio*, the less light (signal) that is collected, the lower the *SNR* will be.

Comment: I take it the Finepix s8600 is the same no long exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the button underneath the zoom adjuster that looks like multiple photos. Then select the proper shot setting.